# Two Same MongoDB queries one yeild results one empty responce

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.posts.find({comments:{$elemMatch:{user:'Khan'}}})
db.posts.find({comments:{$elemMatch:{user:'khan'}}})
```

this is really a mind twister for me, above are two $elemMatch search queries i use in MongoDb shell, i typed these in Code Studio, when i copy paste first line in shell it return nothing, when i copy paste the 2nd line in shell, expected result is returned...
both are same then why the response is different??? 
[image: shell screenshot]
following is the posts collection in the db

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5eda19c6a38d4418e311e43b"
    },
    "title": "post1",
    "body": "body of post 1",
    "category": "news",
    "tags": [
        "news",
        "events"
    ],
    "user": {
        "name": "author name",
        "status": "author"
    },
    "date": "Fri Jun 05 2020 15:09:10 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)",
    "likes": 6,
    "comments": [
        {
            "user": "mehtab",
            "body": "this is some comments 1",
            "date": "Fri Jun 05 2020 16:47:17 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"
        },
        {
            "user": "khan",
            "body": "this is some comments 2",
            "date": "Fri Jun 05 2020 16:47:17 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"
        },
        {
            "user": "saad",
            "body": "this is some comments 3",
            "date": "Fri Jun 05 2020 16:47:17 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"
        }
    ]
}
```

MongoDB 4.2.7 Community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two queries are indeed different. One has the first letter upper-cased, and one does not, and string-matching is case-sensitive.

Uppercase K:

```
db.posts.find({comments:{$elemMatch:{user:'Khan'}}})
```

Lowercase k:

```
db.posts.find({comments:{$elemMatch:{user:'khan'}}})
```

Comment: YES YES YES... got it working... (just started learning mongoDB a couple of hours ago)...

Comment: i was expecting some textual response in case nothing was found/matched...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you want to know why this happens and me too, but following the [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition), if you specify a single query predicate in the $elemMatch expression, $elemMatch is not necessary.

Since the $elemMatch only specifies a single condition, the $elemMatch expression is not necessary, and instead you can use the following query:

```
db.posts.find(
   { "comments.user": "Khan" }
)
```

Comment: A good tip, but I'd offer it in a comment, rather than an answer (as it doesn't actually solve the OP's issue). Note - I've already identified the problem and posted an answer.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the advertising. I will make sure to do the right way next time :)

Comment: aaahhh yes, i read this in the docs, and google and/or stackoverflow has this as well... Docs says its not necessary, though it should work ... and there i was stuck... when it should work it should work...